# Does Docker COPY --link ignore .dockerignore?

Tags: docker

I have 20 GB of test files in my directory, which are excluded by `.dockerignore`. Using `COPY . .` is instant but `COPY --link . .` takes nearly a minute.

The documentation at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/ doesn't mention anything about `.dockerignore` and states:

> If you don’t rely on the behavior of following symlinks in the
> destination path, using --link is always recommended. The performance
> of --link is equivalent or better than the default behavior and, it
> creates much better conditions for cache reuse.

However in my case the performance is extremely worse.

Does the link parameter disable `.dockerignore`?

### Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4
FROM clux/muslrust:1.69.0-nightly-2023-02-15 AS chef
USER root
RUN cargo install cargo-chef
WORKDIR /app

FROM chef AS planner
ARG CARGO_INCREMENTAL=0
COPY --link . . <--- this takes a long time
...
```

### .dockerignore

```
*
!src
!Cargo.toml
!Cargo.lock
!data/default.toml
!data/favicon.ico
!data/example.ttl   
!data/*.html
!data/*.css
!fonts
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt `copy --link` ignores `.dockerignore`, but you could easily test it out - just try copying something not in the context (i.e. excluded by the `.dockerignore`) and see if it succeeds.

I suspect the performance penalty of the `--link` option is just due to the extra work it must perform to make the layer 'independent' of the preceding layers. The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy---link) suggests using the `--link` option is equivalent to doing two builds so you would expect some performance penalty. Exactly how much will be dependent on the base images, layers, etc. in specific builds.

Comment: In that case the sentence "The performance of --link is equivalent or better than the default behavior" in the documentation would be wrong, especially with such a large difference of it being more than 100 times slower.

Comment: Yes, I would agree that that statement is surprising in light of your example and the other elements of the documentation. Someone with more in-depth knowledge of the actually working of the build tool would need to explain it better.